# Store/retrieve arbitrary data that is programmatically updatable via API

Tags: marketing-cloud

My desire is store a string value inside Salesforce that I can periodically update from a Python/Django back-end. I would like to be able to append this string value to the end of each link that appears inside the email (manually is fine, automatically is better). I've looked into creating data extensions which I've been able to update via the Python FuelSDK, but haven't been successful retrieving the value from the data extension for inclusion in the email template. Which is to say, I don't believe data extensions work well for what I need to accomplish. I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction how I might properly handle this. Any assistance one may provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the data in a data extension, then pulling it into an email can be accomplished with AMPScript.  Specifically the Lookup() function identified here:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/

In order to append that onto a link, the concat() function can be used to bring the variable together with the link that is hard-coded:
https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/